# What bug tracker can we use on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install a bug tracker on My raspberry pi for a small amount of user (<10)
Does anyone try this before?

Thank you.

Comment: You could probably run trac - especially if you back it with sqlite rather than postgres, I don't think Jira is an option do to size and resource requirements. If you are connected to the internet you will have a lot more options including, Google Code, Github, bitbucket and a slew of other services - which will also provide source control and project management features.

Comment: You should answer your own question to help those who come after you.

Comment: I will, when I will have something interesting to say. I did not try anything yet...

Comment: About to try roundup ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Trac (0.12.5) successfully on a Raspberry Pi model 2. I have integrated Trac with subversion(SVN 1.8) running on the same RPi. Performance is fine - page loads are typically around 1s.

I blogged about [installing trac and SVN on the Raspberry Pi](http://davidcozenssoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/installing-svn-and-trac-on-raspberry-pi.html).

If you decide to follow what I have done please read the related posts - especially the one on performance, my initial install used mod_python, I then switched to mod_wsgi to improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.org) (Open Source Edition). I've just installed it and it seems to work fine.

You need an Apache/nginx + PHP + PostgreSQL/MySQL stack to get it up. See further [environment requirements](http://issues.thebuggenie.com/wiki/TheBugGenie:FAQ).

My Setup: Nginx 1.6.2 + php-fpm 5.4.3 + PostgreSQL 9.1. (Raspberry Pi Model B overclocked)

The system has really great features (including Wiki etc.) and powerful workflows. It has a VCS integration (e.g. Git repository) and you can even configure an external mail server (e.g. Gmail) for the notifications.

Unfortunately the avg. time for loading pages on my Pi  (depending on the requested data)  is almost within acceptable limits: 3-5s. I think if with a SQLite db, it would run a bit faster. But I will keep "tuning up" PHP, nginx and PostgreSQL in the hope that I improve the page load time.

Just in case if you decide to give it a try, an important hint:

During the installation process, you will have to provide the database connection settings, but the db initialization takes really really long (about 15 minutes). So I had to increase the request timeout in nginx and php.

I worked before with Redmine, GitLab, JIRA and Mantis on a VPS, and I can say Redmine and GitLab are really great but I think Ruby On Rails must be very slow on the Pi. JIRA is a java based application = ressource hungry. Mantis is also a lightweight PHP based web application but I didn't try it, because I find its UI very very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried Trac on my RPi 2 and it works pretty well.  I did not try to integrate it with any version control; simply the bare minimum to get Trac up and running on the RPi.

First install system requirements:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apache2-utils daemontools-run python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

We install `apache2-utils` for a basic auth password file, `daemontools-run` to setup a process supervisor to start and keep Trac running across reboots, and `python-setuptools` / `pip` / `virtualenv` to cleanly install Trac in its own self-contained environment.

The environment and Trac install is done with:

```
sudo virtualenv /opt/trac
sudo /opt/trac/bin/pip install trac==1.0
```

Once Trac is installed create a project:

```
/opt/trac/bin/trac-admin /home/pi/project initenv
```

Let's create a user:

```
htpasswd -c /home/pi/project/.htpasswd user1
```

Note that `-c` in the command above is only for the first user, to create additional users use:

```
htpasswd /home/pi/project/.htpasswd user2
```

In order to get Trac to start after the RPi is rebooted, we can use `daemontools` which is a super easy way to start a program and restart it if it crashes.  Create the file `/home/pi/project/run` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash


/opt/trac/bin/tracd -s --port 8000 --basic-auth="*,/home/pi/project/.htpasswd,project" /home/pi/project
```

And then add it to daemontools' supervisor with the command:

```
sudo update-service --add /home/pi/project
```

You *might* need a reboot for daemontools to kick on if you just installed it; I can't remember.  I'd try to access the page as described below and if the browser connection fails reboot.

Now, access port 8000 on your RPi through a browser and you should be up and running!

[image: bare bones Trac install]

More information on installation can be found on the [Trac install wiki page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall).